# onChange?: (ValueType, ActionMeta) => void, is incompatible with OptionType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-select

I constantly getting an error from flow that `react-select`. This is happened after updating to `v2.4.2`. This is clear that I am passing a right types to the handle change which expect an array with objects + OptionType is accepting any string `[string]: any`. Can any one explain why it is happening or this is potential bug in the react-select flow type?

**error from flow**

```
Error:Error:line (104)Cannot create `Select` element because array type [1] is incompatible with `OptionType` [2] in the first argument of property `onChange`.
    Error:Error:line (104)Cannot create `Select` element because array type [1] is incompatible with null [2] in the first argument of property `onChange`.
    Error:Error:line (104)Cannot create `Select` element because array type [1] is incompatible with undefined [2] in the first argument of property `onChange`.
```

**component example**

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

type LabelValueObject = Object & {
    value: string,
    label: string
}

type State = {
    options: LabelValueObject[],
    selectedOptions: LabelValueObject[],
}

export class ServiceDropdown extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            options: [],
            selectedOptions: null,
        };
    }

    handleChange = (selectedOptions: LabelValueObject[]): void => {
        this.setState({ selectedOptions });
    };

    render() {
        const { selectedOptions } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <Select
                    isMulti
                    isSearchable
                    onChange={this.handleChange}    <=== flow error
                    value={selectedOptions}
                    options={this.state.options}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default ServiceDropdown;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function received by `onChange` is typed as follows:

```
onChange: (ValueType, ActionMeta) => void,
```

`ValueType` is defined as follows:

```
type ValueType = OptionType | OptionsType | null | void
```

where `OptionsType = Array<OptionType>`.

([Reference](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/src/types.js))

So based on that you should also add the value type, `null` and `undefined/void` to the type of `handleChange`.

```
 handleChange = (selectedOptions: LabelValueObject | LabelValueObject[] | null | void) => { ... }
```

Comment: so you mean onChange expects two values? like onChange={this.handle, null} or my actual function should have the second variable.

Comment: No. Your **type** has to handle more than the array of values. It has to be similar to the original ValueType shown above. I have updated my answer with an example of how your type should look like.